# Встраивание программы проверки пароля в алгоритм работы утилиты htpasswd

Tags: c, apache

У меня стоит задача написать программу проверки пароля для пользователей web-сервера и встроить эту программу в алгоритм работы утилиты htpasswd для проверки вводимого пользователем пароля на соблюдение моих условий. 
Программа написана, но как ее встроить в алгоритм htpasswd?

Comment: Путём правки исходного кода htpasswd?

Comment: В задании не сказано, но думаю, что да